# Enthought Numeric Traits Unit of Measure?

Tags: enthought

Do Enthought, numeric Traits support a unit of measure attribute?

I could not find this discussed in the documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not. You may find Enthought's [scimath.units](https://github.com/enthought/scimath) helpful, however.